# Mandatory based on value of another column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-form

I am Creating a new item inventory form on sharepoint and need a Yes/No column to make another column Mandatory if the input=yes eg. =IF[____]="yes",[----] is now required. Also, how can i change the values of other columns if the result of Yes/No= yes eg. =IF[_____]="yes",[------]=0

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you'll need to use Form Validation. It's similar to column/field validation but you're able to reference any column in the calculation.

To get to validation settings go to...
1. List/Library Settings
2. Under General Settings, click 'Validation Settings'
3. From there you can enter your required formula and error message.

The formula wants to evaluate to TRUE or YES if you want the submission to be successful. FALSE or NO if you want the validation to show an error and prevent submission.

Try something like

```
=AND(
   [My_Boolean_Field] == "YES", 
   NOT(
      ISBLANK(
         [My_Now_Required_Field]
      )
   )
)
```

Now, for the changing other values... I'd suggest either something to do with calculated columns, which use a similar logic to Validation but you can set their values, or a workflow.

The easiest way would be with a workflow from SharePoint Designer. You can just say "On item edit" and "On item creation" run workflow and change values based off those requirements. You can set almost any field type from SharePoint Designer directly. The only ones I'm unsure about are Calculated columns, and Managed Metadata columns.

The method that would put the least amount of strain on your farm would be to use calculated columns. You may need a couple new columns involved here but what I'd do is set the calculation to this:

```
=IF([My_Other_Boolean]=="Yes", 0, [The_Other_Number_Field])
```

This'll give you the ability to set your calculated column to 0 if a specific field is "Yes". Otherwise it'll take the default value of whatever other number field you're referencing. Then leave a description under "The Other Number Field" mentioning that if your boolean field is "Yes" this value is assumed to be 0.

In your display form then, you can set the calculated column to be what's displayed, and the other number field is only displayed in the edit and creation form.

If you need further explanation, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using jquery according to [link to a post using jquery](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88064/hide-show-field-on-list-form-based-on-value-from-another-field), A.Saéed's answer provides the code, you just need to adapt it a little for your own purposes.

You will need to familiarise yourself with using web parts too, since you would need to edit the actual form to insert a web part, select a `Media and Content`>`Script Editor` web part, then paste in the code.  In case you've not done this before, [here's a link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20901/how-to-add-jquery-to-a-single-page) to get your research started.